# mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/home/mysqltmp/ibXXX' Permission denied

Tags: mysql, permissions, service, mariadb

My main volume is a 20GB SSD disk mounted on /. I have a 4TB HDD mounted in /home. So to save space I want to set the mysql temporary directory to /home/mysqltmp.

However when I set to this directory mysql won't start. I get error:

```
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/home/mysqltmp/ibm7cVN0' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
```

I checked the permission and it is correct:

```
# ls -ld /home/mysqltmp/
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 Apr  4 03:19 /home/mysqltmp/
```

Running mysqld as root it starts without problem.

Server:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Note: Problem arose after updating to 16.04, was working on 14.04

MySQL details:

```
# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Comment: Please add the /home permissions (`ls -ld /home`), the /home/mysqltmp/ibm7cVN0 permissions (ditto) and the user/group runing the MySQL server (see inside **my.cnf** file). Also, check if filesystem has enough free space and inodes (`df -h` and `df -hi`), and if is mounted rw (`mount` or `findmnt` or `cat /proc/mounts`)

Comment: Those are _probably_ `mysql` and `mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be UMASK values. Please check umask.

To change the default UMASK value, start mysqld_safe as follows:

```
$ UMASK=384  # = 600 in octal
$ export UMASK
$ mysqld_safe &
```

By default, MySQL creates database directories with an access permission value of 0750. To modify this behavior, set the UMASK_DIR variable. If you set its value, new directories are created with the combined UMASK and UMASK_DIR values. For example, to give group access to all new directories, start mysqld_safe as follows:

```
$ UMASK_DIR=504  # = 770 in octal
$ export UMASK_DIR
$ mysqld_safe &
```